# Nginx give access to subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, nginx

We're running a Wordpress site on a Nginx server, I am now trying to install Piwik there in the /stats folder.

This is the default Nginx configuration that came with the install, I added the "/stats" block myself, but it doesn't work - it gets rendered by WordPress whenever I go to mysite.com/stats instead of going to that folder.

Desired behavior would be that the /stats subdirectory (and all files and directories in it) is just parsed by PHP as would be on a default install without Nginx rules

Any clue what I'm missing?

```
server_name  _;
port_in_redirect off;

client_header_buffer_size 4k;
client_body_buffer_size 128k;
client_max_body_size 16m;

root   /var/www/html;
index  index.html index.php;

charset utf-8;

log_not_found off;

gzip_static on;
gzip_types text/css application/javascript text/xml;
gzip_vary on;
gzip on;


# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^.*$ /index.php?$args;
}

error_page  404 @rewrite;

# Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

# WP Multisite rewrites
rewrite /([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) /$2 last;
rewrite /([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ /$2 last;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.gz $uri/ @rewrite;
}

location ~ \.sql$ {
    rewrite ^.*$ /index.php?$args;
}

# We do not want to run php from wp uploads
location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
    rewrite ^.*$ /index.php?$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }
    fastcgi_pass             127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index            index.php;
    include                  fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param            SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
}

location /stats {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    index index.php;
}

location = /favicon.ico {
    access_log off;
    expires 2w;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
}

location ~* \.(js|css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|woff|woff2|ttf|otf|eot|pdf|xml|mp4|ogg|mp3|mov|wmv|avi|cur|rtf|txt|swf)$ {
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    expires 2w;
    try_files $uri $uri.gz;
}
```

Comment: try using *location \stats {*

Comment: When you access to `/stats`, you request reaches `location /stat`. Then directive `try_files` works and if no static files, which match `$uri $uri/` are found, then `/index.php?$args` will be processed. And then `location ~ \.php$` do what it have to do.

Comment: semm0, unfortunately that didn't help.

Vladislav, I am not really sure I follow you, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules for multi-site WordPress, particularly this one: `rewrite /([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ /$2 last;` will redirect any `/stats/index.php` URI back to WordPress's `/index.php`.

If you are not using a multi-site WordPress, you can safely delete the redundant rewrite rules.

If you *are* using a multi-site WordPress, some redesign is required.

Comment: So I completely missed that line :/ thanks, that works !